# How to set up TeamCity for Build -> Test -> Deploy flow

Tags: unit-testing, build, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have configured TeamCity with Git to get my ASP.NET MVC project.

My solution contains the web app and the corresponding unit tests:

```
MY_SOLUTION.sln:

 - WebAppProject
 - SomeCoreLibrary
 - SomeCoreLibraryTests 
 - OtherProjects...
```

The steps that I have configured in TeamCity are the following:

1. Get external packages using NuGet
2. Build the solution and deploy it
3. Run Unit Tests
4. Run Automated Tests (using Selenium)

I want **to run the unit tests after building but before deployment** and stop deployment if the unit tests failed. Currently the deployment is done after the build using the following Command Line Parameters:

```
/p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0
/p:DeployOnBuild=true I want this to be done only after SomeCoreLibraryTests.dll unit tests have passed 
/p:PublishProfile=MyWebDeploy
/P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
/P:UserName=username_here 
/P:Password=password_here
```

Thanks,
Ionut

Comment: As written, it's hard to tell what you're having trouble with. Can you elaborate on what isn't working?

Comment: I have changed the Question title. I want to know how to build the solution, run some unit tests after the solution has been built and then to deploy the built solution only if the unit tests have passed.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in similar cases is to use RoboCopy to just mirror the new website into the deployment path. Doesn't that work for you?

---

P.S.: if you do get this working, I'd suggest doing a performance improvement change in TeamCity (which would allow you to run the unit tests in parallel to the automated tests):

I assume you are employing a single build configuration for all those steps. If that is the case, what I would recommend instead is using [Dependent Build configurations](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Chain) to separate the different concerns. You can see an example here in an open source project of mine:

http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewLog.html?buildId=112432&buildTypeId=bt1075&tab=dependencies

*Log in as Guest and expand the Testeroids :: Publish to NuGet tree node to visualize the build flow.*

To achieve this, basically you pass around the result of your build step in the artifacts (e.g. you pass the resulting binaries from **Compile** into **Unit Test**). You gain several things by using dependent builds: several independent build steps can run in parallel on different agents, plus if one of your build steps fails because of external factors (e.g. let's say **Publish** failed because the network went down), you can trigger again the build and it will only rebuild the failed steps.

Comment: Do I really need to make 2 build configurations in order to take the build objects (.dlls, etc.) in order to deploy? Can't I just do it in the same build configuration? Also as a note, I am not deploying to IIS as a zip package, but I deploy it using a publish profile (and the MSBuild uses that publish profile to deploy it /p:DeployOnBuild=true). I just want to postpone this DeployOnBuild=true action after the unit tests have passed.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind regarding separating the compilation step from the deployment step is diving into the MSBuild target file to understand what is really going on when you say DeployOnBuild=true. Perhaps you can replicate just that step by passing /target=Deploy or /target=Publish. You would need to look into the script file to find out the exact target name being used. Also, using one build configuration instead of 2 in TeamCity is always possible, but the more I move towards dependent builds, the more I get the impression that that is the way they intended it to be used like.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the tools that you use. However, I would, in general, use a few build configurations for a project:

1. build configuration, triggered on change, containing these steps: get the latest source code and packages, build/compile and unit test. Then create an artifact for deployment task.
2. build configuration to deploy to a development server, triggered by successful completion of and using artifact (via dependency) from (1).
3. build configuration for long running (eg integration/functional) testing that is scheduled to run less frequently.

An advantage of (2) is that you can, if necessary, re-deploy a build/artifact without having to rebuild the artifact first. Also, if you have multiple agents, (2) and (3) can run independently of each other.

Furthermore, you can also tag build in (2) that have passed development checks and then use its artifact in another build configuration to deploy it to test server, etc.